# How to print directly to "Tray 2" without looping through all papersources

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

Right now, the code is looping through each printer source to get the papersource name `Tray 2`

Is there a faster method instead of looping through all the sources? It is printing slow because I believe the code is communicating with the printer each time for each papersource. Since this is a network printer, it may take up to a minute to print!

One solution I can think of is to load all the papersources into an array then find `Tray 2` but I'm not sure how to do this.

Another solution is to just print directly to source name with `Tray 2` but how?

The code below is what we currently have:

```
private void reportPrintingSystem_StartPrint(object sender, PrintDocumentEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Count; i++)
        if (e.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSources[i].SourceName.Equals("Tray 2"))
        {
            e.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = e.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSources[i];
            e.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entire code is really unnecessary and can be skipped if default print setting is ok. In our environment, some printers may need specific settings and if this is needed, then step through the code and find the array with the desired papersource and hard code it in.